# Adding Shapes to a New Visio Document

Tags: c#, office-interop, visio

I have this code that creates a new Visio document and adds a rectangle.  It works, but I don't like having to open another document to get the Masters collection from it.  The issue is the new document has an empty Masters shape collection. I couldn't find a method in the Document class to add shapes to the Masters collection and all the examples I could find for adding shapes assumed you had an existing document. Is there a better way to do what I want?

```
// create the new application
Visio.Application va = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Application();

        // add a document
        va.Documents.Add(@"");

       // Visio.Documents vdocs = va.Documents;

        // we need this document to get its Masters shapes collection
        // since our new document has none 
        Visio.Document vu = vdocs.OpenEx(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft       Office\Office12\1033\Basic_U.vss", (short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.VisOpenSaveArgs.visOpenDocked);

        // set the working  document to our new document
        Visio.Document vd = va.ActiveDocument;

        // set the working page to the active page
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Page vp = va.ActivePage;

      // if we try this from the Masters collection from our new document
      // we get a run time since our masters collection is empty
     Visio.Master vm  = vu.Masters.get_ItemU(@"Rectangle");
    Visio.Shape visioRectShape = vp.Drop(vm, 4.25, 5.5);
        visioRectShape.Text = @"Rectangle text.";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right - the Masters collection is ReadOnly. Documents normally start off with an empty masters collection. The collection gets populated by dropping masters from a stencil document.

If you want to create a new document with a pre-populated Masters collection then you could create your own template (.vst) and then base your new document on that. For example:

```
Visio.Document vDoc = vDocs.Add("MyTemplateFile.vst");
```

Normally you would package your stencils and templates together and then always create shapes by dropping a master from the respective stencil document (.vss).

Masters also have a MatchByName property. Dropping a master when this property is set to true, Visio first checks that a master of the same exists in the drawing document masters collection. If it does an instance of that master will be dropped. If not a new master will be added based on the original stencil. Have a look at these two links for more information:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa201768%28office.10%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff766298.aspx

If you really want to create your own masters in code, you can draw / drop your own shapes on the page and then use the Document.Drop method to add it to the masters collection.

Also if you want to use a master by name then you'll need to loop through the masters collection to check that it exists before you use it.

Comment: thanks.  Do you know of a decent forum and/or some good resources for generating Visio documents programattically?  I spent a few hours on this yesterday and mostly fumbled my way through.  I still have some questions such as how do I figure out what connection points a shape has and how can I address a specific connection point?

Comment: Check out these two links  
 [Analyze Connectivity Between Process Flows - VisGuy.com](http://www.visguy.com/2009/04/22/analyze-connectivity-between-process-flows/)  
 [Create Visio Flowcharts Programmatically - VisGuy.com](http://www.visguy.com/2006/09/13/create-visio-flowcharts-programmatically/)

Comment: Also, in no particular order:
  
  [Visio Automation - Saveen Reddy on CodePlex](http://visioautomation.codeplex.com/)
  [Visio Guy forum](http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php)
  [TechNet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/visiogeneral/threads)
  [Developing Visio Solutions - old but a great resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa245244%28office.10%29.aspx)
  [Visio 2010 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=12365)

and for a comprehensive list, I'd have a look at [the links section on VisGuy.com](http://www.visguy.com/visio-links/)

Comment: thanks for the links, they have been helpful.  The VisioAutomation looks interesting but I am having trouble finding the docs.  I have sent a message to Saveen letting him know the link isn't working.

Comment: Just an update to the VisioAutomation link above that moved a while ago from CodePlex to GitHub: https://github.com/saveenr/VisioAutomation

Answer (score 2):

I think you will find this on-line book extremely useful : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa245244(v=office.10).aspx

Comment: thanks.  I have bee going through that - I found it this week.  It has been helpful.